# Android - parse date array

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing, date

how can I to parse String Array of dates?

```
String startTime[] = stdata.toArray(new String[stdata.size()]);
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");



        for(int ir=0;ir<startTime.length;ir++){
        try {
            parsed2d[ir] = inputFormat.parse(startTime[ir]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

With this code I get:
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

EDITED:

@Juvanis you are right!

FINAL CODE WORKING:

```
String startTime[] = stdata.toArray(new String[stdata.size()]);
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");



        for(int ir=0;ir<startTime.length;ir++){
        try {
            Date parsed2d[] = new Date[startTime.length];
            parsed2d[ir] = inputFormat.parse(startTime[ir]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: _parsed2d_ array highly possibly has less elements than _startTime_ array. Be careful!

Comment: `Date parsed2d[] = new Date[startTime.length];` it should be outside the `for` loop

Comment: I'm passing the parsed data to another date var which is outside the for - here I posted just one part of the code.